# install visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio

i am trying  to install visual studio 2008   because as i know     studio 2010 does not support  Boost library  but problem is that i can't find official link for download visual studio 2008  maybe because 2010  version is avaliable  ?or?i have searched yes there is many other sites but can i  download it from microsoft?
:EDITED
 i have installed visual studio 2008 i have also downloaded boost library    1_43.0 please can anybody tell me how use   boost in visual c++ 2008

Comment: Why dp you think boost doesn't support VC10?

Comment: i have asked many people and they told me

Comment: Do they mean it doesn't support .NET 4 rather than VS2010?

Comment: AFAIK VC10 support boost. It is actually on the list of tested compilers on boost. See http://www.boost.org/users/download/version_1_44_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after the express edition? The 2008 versions are still available from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP)

If you're after Professional or higher edition, do you have MSDN license? I can still find them in there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which Visual Studio Express that you're after, supposedly this is the download for [Visual Studio 2008 Express C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP)